# How to grab system audio to python?

Tags: python, events, audio, listener

I want to process audio being played by the OS before it is played by the sound device.
I am trying to detect audio from files like *mp3* and *wav*.
I do not want to read the binary data of the files using methods like `fread()` directly.
Is it possible in Python to set up a *listener* that can grab the audio from OS in real-time?

Comment: With "the audio will be processed by python before load to sounddevice" you mean you want to write a program that changes the audio? (filtering, enhancing, etc.) I.e. a DSP (digital signal processing) component? If that's the case, then Python is likely not the best tool for this task.

Comment: Basically are you actually just asking how to grab audio with Python as the title suggests or do you want to do real-time audio processing as your text implies?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to make changes to the meaning of their question without the OP clarifying it themselves, but whatever.

Comment: @blubberdiblub thanks for your reply. I mean that just like DSP in front of sounddevice. not just real time processing . it should process ALL of the sound the PC would play.

Answer (score 0):

1. See [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38756/real-time-audio-input-output-in-python-with-pyaudio) for a [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) example.
2. The [Open Sound System](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ossaudiodev.html) is also an option. (Might not work on Windows)